# Why do you need to convert a variable to duration but not a raw integer?

Tags: go

If I want to sleep for 2 seconds I can do the following:

```
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

but when I do:

```
test := 2
time.Sleep(test * time.Second)
```

It throws the error

> invalid operation: test * time.Second (mismatched types int and
>   time.Duration)

I can fix this by casting `test` like so: `time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(5)) * time.Second)` but i'm wondering why it is that I need to wrap it in `time.Duration` when it's a variable and not when it's a raw value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that you pass a `const` in the first case of `2 * time.Second` and a `var` in the second case where you declare `test := 2`. Read [this blog post about constants in Go](https://blog.golang.org/constants) for more details.

Basically, a const literal in the code will be converted to the type that makes sense for the surrounding expression. In the first case `2 * time.Duration` this means that the `2` is converted to a `time.Duration` while in the second case `test := 2` the `2` is assigned to the `test` variable. This means that the type inference happens at that point, giving `test` the type `int` which is the default type for the literal `2`. If you used the literal `2.0` instead, the `test` variable would have type `float64` instead. However, the expression `test * time.Second` has the type of `test` already set and it is different from the type of `time.Duration` which is why you get that compiler error.

Comment: "a const literal": To be precise: an untyped const literal.